# Split a dictionary into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm sure this is very easy:

If I have the following:

```
 mydict = { 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', ... , 'keyn': 'valuen' }
```

How can I end up w/ a list such as:

```
 result = [ { 'key1': 'value1'}, { 'key2': 'value2' }, ...., 'keyn': 'valuen' }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = [{k: v} for (k, v) in mydict.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is list comprehension

```
mydict = { 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', ... , 'keyn': 'valuen' }
new_list = [{k: v} for k, v in mydict.iteritems()]
```

or not so interesting version

```
map(lambda x, y: {x: y}, mydict.iteritems())
```